# Team menu missing on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, team-foundation-server

Yesterday it was working, I didn't install anything...

Today I turned on my PC and the menu is gone.

How can I restore this menu?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/restore-original-settings-for-buttons-commands-or-toolbars-HP005195111.aspx) is an article in microsoft knowledge base. This should help.

Comment: That's for 2003... I need for 2010

Comment: yeah but you've forgotten to say that in the question.

Comment: ok here is a guide for 2007 i guess it haven't changed in 2010 [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/add-a-button-menu-or-command-to-a-toolbar-or-menu-HA010154027.aspx#BM2)